# Can a part of the group remain stealthy when combat starts?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, stealth, sneak-attack

A group of 4 PCs roll Dexterity (Stealth) checks. They sneak around and 3 of them get noticed by the enemy (because of line of sight or just bad Dexterity (Stealth) rolls). Combat starts, everyone rolls initiative.

If the remaining PC has a Dexterity (Stealth) roll higher than the enemy's passive Perception, does he remain hidden? Can he then go around to get an attack with advantage on that enemy (while remaining out of sight)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The character simply wouldn't be detected yet at the first round of combat and would fall under the rules for the "Hide" combat action, and thus the "Unseen Attacker/Target" rules. The other stipulations you were probably already following as per a normal stealth roll (p177 PHB).  If they were only being quiet, for example, the successful stealth check may not matter anyway since the enemy is now looking directly at them.

Comment: This may be true RAW, but shouldn't it depend at least in part on whether the opponent knows/expects the party to be together?

Comment: @R..: No. Why would it? Whether a character is hidden depends solely on his Stealth roll (assuming he's still able to hide behind something) contested by the enemy's Passive Perception (or an active Perception check if the enemy spends an action to search for him). That said, the character would stop being hidden if he no longer has anything obscuring him from the enemy (e.g. if he tries to walk into melee range). Surprise is what would be canceled by the enemy noticing any threat at all.

Comment: @V2Blast: OK, that's probably what I was confusing it with.

Answer (score 1):

They would be "hidden" but would NOT have surprise. The stelth check is an individual check, so it would only be an individual fail. However, if say all 4 PCs are clustered in a group walking down a hallway of a dungeon or castle. The ones that fail would obviously expose the "hidden" ones. There is even an exception to this. If the Halfling is mixed into the group and passed the stealth, he would remain hidden if there is a larger PC in the group. The reason the others give away the ones that passed is because that changes the DC number needing to succeed to nearly impossible if you are the same size as the ones that failed.

Answer (score 1):

The rules on Hiding are:

> **Until you are discovered or you stop hiding, ...** (PHB p.177)

The PC you describe has *not* been discovered and has *not* stopped hiding, therefore they retain all the benefits of being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the dm because if he’s doing s group check you succeed or fail as a group. If that’s the case then no you do not stay hidden.

Comment: This is a good start to an answer, but you should expand it to cite the relevant rule and explain when it may or may not be applied.

Comment: “Cite” means what page to find it on, not copy the whole rule into the post.